# "At peak" without implying it'll never improve again?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-usage, phrase-requests

If something is currently at it's highest state ever achieved (so the right-most point on a graph would be the highest point) I have a tendency to want to say that it's "at its peak", but as far as I know, "peak" actually implies something like the maximum point that it not only has, but will *ever* achieve. It's not really a "peak" until it stops increasing and starts decreasing, and it's only "the peak" if it will never again make it that high.

What then is a more correct way of saying "as high as it's ever been, and still going"? Or have I got "peak" wrong above?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps an expert in graphs and curve patterns could give you a better answer but I suggest  "**so far it's been an upward curve pattern**" and "**X marks my record high**" or "**marks my best achievement so far**".

Comment: "record high" is extremely close, although doesn't seem to convey a continuing increase. it's more like "a new highest peak".

Answer (score 1):

Either **all-time high** or **record high** (suggested by Centaurus) are perfect phrases to use.

You can see both of those phrases used when describing the American stock market, which is as high as it's ever been and probably will continue going higher.

Here's a [recent article](http://news.investors.com/technology-click/042015-748626-nflx-stock-hits-all-time-high.htm) talking about Netflix stock:

> Netflix stock hit a record high for the third straight trading day on Monday
>
> Netflix hit an all-time high of 576.13 in morning trading on the stock market today.